# Evaluating $\arctan\left(\sin\frac12(\beta-x)\csc\frac12(\beta+x)\right)$ when $x=\pi$

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the following:

$$\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos\beta\cos x} - 2\cot\beta \arctan\left(\sin \left(\frac{\beta-x}{2}\right) \csc \left(\frac{\beta+x}{2}\right)\right)$$

This is the result of an integral and I need to evaluate at $x = \pi$ and $x=0$.

The first part of the expression evaluates to zero for both $x = \pi$ (upper limit) and $x=0$ (lower limit). For $x=0$, I think the expression yields $0.5\pi \cot\beta$.  I'm getting stuck when $x=\pi$ although I suspect that this also evaluates to $0.5\pi \cot\beta$

Comment: If you're looking for a simplified answer instead of solving a complicated integral, just use WolframAlpha, Mathematica, Maple, etc.

Comment: Yes, i did use WolframAlpha to get the indefinite integral, but it would not provide me with a solution for the definite integral and I have the Pro version.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint:$$\sin (a+b)=\sin a \cos b  + \cos a \sin b $$so when you put $x=\pi$ you will have \begin{align*}\sin (\frac{\beta-x}{2}) \csc (\frac{\beta+x}{2})& =  \frac{\sin (\frac{\beta-x}{2})}{\sin (\frac{\beta+x}{2})}= \frac{\sin (\frac{\beta-\pi}{2})}{\sin (\frac{\beta+\pi}{2})}\\& =\frac{\sin \frac{\beta}{2}\cos \frac{\pi}{2}-\cos \frac{\beta}{2}\sin \frac{\pi}{2} }{\sin \frac{\beta}{2}\cos \frac{\pi}{2}+\cos \frac{\beta}{2}\sin \frac{\pi}{2}}  \\& =\frac{0-\cos \frac{\beta}{2}\sin \frac{\pi}{2}}{0+\cos \frac{\beta}{2}\sin \frac{\pi}{2}}= -1\end{align*} now you deal with $\arctan(-1)$

Comment: And the arctan of - 1 is $\frac{-\pi}{4}$ which then results in $0.5\cot\beta$.  So the answer then is $\pi\cot\beta$.  Thanks.  P.S.  I wonder why Wolfram Alpha couldn't evaluate this definite integral. It seems straightforward now that you showed me the piece of the puzzle I was missing.